# Get List of StorageFile ordered by type

Tags: c#, uwp

I was trying to get a sorted list of files this way:

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, fileTypeFilter);

queryOptions.SortOrder.Clear();

SortEntry se = new SortEntry();
se.PropertyName = "System.ItemType";
se.AscendingOrder = false;            
queryOptions.SortOrder.Add(se);
```

.....

```
var queryResult = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
```

but this code gets on exception:

> "System.ArgumentException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [QueryOptions.SortOrder Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.queryoptions.sortorder) has explained clearly:

> If the folder being queried is not in a library or in the HomeGroup folder, SortOrder only supports entries based on the System.ItemNameDisplay (PKEY_ItemNameDisplay), System.Search.Rank (PKEY_Search_Rank), or System.DateModified (PKEY_DateModified) properties; SortOrder entries based on any other properties will return E_INVALIDARG.

So, if your `folder` is in other place, your code will not work.